# OCR multiple images into one PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, ocr

Does anyone have experience how to OCR several images and create one output PDF file with recognized text with Nicomsoft OCR in C#? It seems it can do it, but my C# code does not produce any PDF for some reason:

```
NSOCRLib.NSOCRClass NsOCR = new NSOCRLib.NSOCRClass();
NsOCR.Engine_InitializeAdvanced(out CfgObj, out OcrObj, out ImgObj); 
for (i = 0; i < ImageCnt; i++)
{
   NsOCR.Img_LoadFile(ImgObj, ImageFiles[i]);
   NsOCR.Img_OCR(ImgObj, TNSOCR.OCRSTEP_FIRST, TNSOCR.OCRSTEP_LAST, TNSOCR.OCRFLAG_NONE;
   NsOCR.Svr_AddPage(SvrObj, ImgObj, TNSOCR.FMT_EXACTCOPY);
}
NsOCR.Svr_SaveToFile(SvrObj, "c:\\PDF.pdf");
```

I tried different approaches, code execution takes some time so it seems it OCR files, but it does not create PDF file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to create PDF object, try this code:

```
//... declare variables 
NSOCRLib.NSOCRClass NsOCR = new NSOCRLib.NSOCRClass();
NsOCR.Engine_InitializeAdvanced(out CfgObj, out OcrObj, out ImgObj); 
NsOCR.Svr_Create(CfgObj, TNSOCR.SVR_FORMAT_PDF, out SvrObj); //create Saver object, output format is PDF
for (i = 0; i < ImageCnt; i++)
{
   NsOCR.Img_LoadFile(ImgObj, ImageFiles[i]);
   NsOCR.Img_OCR(ImgObj, TNSOCR.OCRSTEP_FIRST, TNSOCR.OCRSTEP_LAST, TNSOCR.OCRFLAG_NONE);
   NsOCR.Svr_AddPage(SvrObj, ImgObj, TNSOCR.FMT_EXACTCOPY);
}
NsOCR.Svr_SaveToFile(SvrObj, "c:\\PDF.pdf");
```